# Prove a function is surjective and injective

Tags: functions

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be any function and let $g$ be the following function:

$g\colon P(X) \to P(Y)$,

$g(S) = \{f(s) : s\in S\}$

Prove that:

1) If $f$ is injective then $g$ is injective.

2) If $f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f(S)=\{f(s)\;:\; s\in S\}$$
and $S\ne S'$ two sets of $\mathcal P(X)$ so WLOG there's $s\in S\setminus S'$ so $f(s)\in f(S)$ and $f(s)\not\in f(S')$ (otherwise there's some $s'\in S'$ s.t. $f(s')=f(s)$ which contradicts the injectivity of $f$) hence we have $f(S)\ne f(S')$ and then $g$ is injective.

For the surjectivity, let $B\in\mathcal P(Y)$ then $A=f^{-1}(B)$ is a subset of $X$ and since $f$ is surjective we have
$$g(A)=f(A)=f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)=B$$
hence $g$ is surjective.

Comment: What is WLOG ???

Comment: Without Loss Of Generality

Comment: In the surjective part, I don´t understand which f is g for me and what f is f for me ... I also don´t quite understand where and how do you use the hypothesis that f is surjective

Comment: $g$ is $f$ but applied on the subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f $ is Surjective, then $\forall y\in Y$ there exists $x\in X s.t, f ( x ) = y$

Now we want to show that $\forall E\in P (Y)$ there exists $D\in P ( X)$ s.t $g (E)=D $.

Let us take $E\in P ( Y ) $, since f is Surjective, $\forall y \in E $ there exists $x\in X$ s.t $ (x) =y$, now let $D $ be the set of all such $x$ so $D\in P ( X ) $.

Now $g (D)=\{f ( x ) | x \in D\}=E $.  Thus g is also Surjective.